# Adding binary columns that indicate the day of the week - AttributeError

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

I have a df which carries a date as index. I want to add additional columns ("Mon"...."Sun"). Let's say 2012-10-03 is a Monday then the "Mon" column should be True and the other columns False.

The df has the shape:

```
Date
2012-10-03    3521.0
2012-10-04    3475.0
2012-10-05    3148.0
2012-10-06    2006.0
2012-10-07    2142.0
2012-10-08    3537.0
```

The desired result should be like:

```
 Date                       Mon    Tue    Wed    Fri    Sat    Sun
    2012-10-03    3521.0    True   False  False  False  False  False
.....
```

For this purpose I use a code which I have found in a book with:

```
days=["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"]
for i in range(7):
    df[days[i]] = (df.index.dayofweek == i).astype(float)
```

Which should work but returns the error:

> AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'dayofweek'

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: could you elaborate on what exactly this 'dayofweek' is?

Comment: IMO this question should NOT be downvoted - it has input sample data set, desired data set and the source code (attempt) that didn't work. I wish  all Pandas questions were asked like this one... Plus one ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the index to `DatetimeIndex` before using `dayofweek`

```
daily.index = pd.to_datetime(daily.index)
```